# Calculate average level likely to be achieved from compounding percentages

Tags: probability, logarithms, percentages

Say I am playing a difficult videogame where the goal is to get to the highest level possible without dying. Now say the chance I have of beating a level is x%. What would the average level achieved by? I assumed that the average would come when getting to a certain level has an exactly 50% chance of happening, so I used the equation $\log_{x/100}0.5$. In the case of an 80% chance, the average level is 3.1062837195054. However, when I coded an algorithm to brute force 1000000 different games, I get the actual average score 4.050343.

What is wrong with my average calculation, or is it correct and my brute-forced average a fluke?

Comment: Where does the logarithm come from? I think your question is related to geometric random variables.

Comment: Hmm I will look at this. Thank you!

Comment: Is the success rate the same for each level?

Comment: Yep. n% each time.